# cudaMalloc doesn't work with template

Tags: c++

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
void gpu_load(T (&data)[N])
{
    cudaMalloc((void**)data, N*sizeof(T));
}
```

I call it like this:

```
float data[2];
gpu_load(data);
```

But it doesn't work. I guss it must be something with the & and points...

Comment: It has nothing to do with CUDA.  You are doing bad things with  this line `(void**)data`.

Comment: @Anycorn `cudaMalloc` takes a `void**`.

Comment: Yes but nvidia Stanford class shows this as an example

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: if you try this, you will see, it loads junk to gpu ram.

Comment: @SkyRipper Of course it will be junk, you are stuffing GPU memory address into a `float[2]` array.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just convert a pointer to a pointer to a pointer.  data is of type `T*` but cudaMalloc wants a `void **`.

Try this:

```
cudaMalloc(static_cast<void**>(&d), N*sizeof(T));
```

Note the new ampersand.

Edit: added the static cast as suggested in the comments.

Comment: where to put static_cast<void**>(&d)?

Comment: @SkyRipper I ran the code and it compiles without any errors. You need to give us more context. And look at the edit to know where `static_cast<void**>(&d)` goes.